# Couldn't install Ubuntu via Live USB: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMID read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, live-usb, nouveau

I tried to install Ubuntu on my laptop which uses Windows 10. I allocated some hard disk space for a Ubuntu partition and started to install Ubuntu 20.04 via Live USB. When the installation completed, it asked me to restart. However, when I restart my computer, firstly it showed me:

nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMID read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4

Then it directly boots into Windows and when I change the boot order, it simply opens GNU GRUB version 2.04. Does that mean Ubuntu is not installed or it uses older grub?

Comment: From the grub menu, select a recovery option under the "Advanced" item.  Then install the proprietary Nvidia drivers.  The recovery mode puts the "nomodeset" onto the kernel boot line to prevent some video problems. Lots of answers on this site for this problem.

Comment: I corrected my question, it opens gnu grub.

Comment: I know how to download drivers via recovery mode. But not sure about gnu grub, Maybe ubuntu is not fully installed?

Comment: You mean you get the grub menu when it opens?  Secure boot should be off to use Nvidia drivers, and Windows power option "fast startup" should be off.

Comment: Well, in one of the tutorial, it was told that I should disable secure boot for ubuntu installation. Anyway, it was disabled by default. Is there any way to enable it?

Comment: Secure Boot is just an option in the UEFI settings.

Comment: I both disabled secure boot and fast startup. Again when I enter ubuntu gnu grub version 2.04 opens automatically. What does that mean?